# Access to 32bit memory address c#

Tags: c#, memory-address, intptr

I'm trying to access a 32bit address, but when i create the IntPtr it throws an OverflowException. Here's the code:

```
uint memAddr = 0xF5920824;
IntPtr bufPtr = new IntPtr(memAddr);
byte[] data = new byte[4];
Marshal.Copy(bufPtr, data, 0, 4);
```

How can i access that address?

Comment: Why do you want to access that address?

Comment: The address you're trying to read is at the 3GB point - depending on your OS I believe that's a restricted address

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: i simply want to improve my knowledge and i'm using a program (done by a friend) that has a hidden value (which i know) at that address.
My OS is Win7 64 bit and i'm using visual studio 32bit (student version), what information do you need?

Comment: @Demon0112 - You are trying to access an illegal address.  Compile your application as a x64 application and it no longer will be illegal.

Comment: Perhaps you need to get a pointer from that program. (Or use Cheat Engine)

Comment: You have memAddr declared as an uint. The constructor to IntPtr takes an int. The value you provided for memAddr causes the overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program **CANNOT** access a memory address of another program (regardless that the address you're going to read can't fit an `Int32`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148177/just-what-is-an-intptr-exactly?rq=1) to understand what it is) simply using an `IntPtr`because they run within their **private address space**.

It must be shared somehow by the first program (shared memory or something else). Moreover an address XYZ in one program *may be* something completely different even in another instance of the same program (because the address is VIRTUAL).

If you're sure about the memory address (how? it could be even necessary to scan process memory) you have to P/Invoke [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it's a function designed for debugging purposes and if your executable has enough privileges you can read the memory of another process.
See [this post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935439/readprocessmemory-and-writeprocessmemory-gone-wrong) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

For such a large number > 2^31-1 you need to compile as 64 bit.

Go to Configuration Manager... and change platform from x86 to Any CPU or x64.

Answer (score 2):

By passing a `uint` to `IntPtr`, you are converting it to a `long`, as `IntPtr` doesn't support unsigned integers. Then, if you are running in a 32-bit process, your `uint` overflows an `int`.

You need to use 64-bit to read that address.