# RPM does work and i can't figure out why

Tags: c#

Keep Searching the internet and can't figure this out, `ReadProcessMemory` is returning just fine so its executing. But the output is always empty. Lenght of the array is `0` as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MemEd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("client")[0];
            byte[] buff = new byte[]{};
            IntPtr bread;
            IntPtr pHandle = OpenProcess(0x0010, false, proc.Id);
            bool check = ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (IntPtr)0x5EFF75B8, buff, 10, out bread);
            if (!check)
                Console.WriteLine("RPM Fail");

            Console.WriteLine(buff.Length); //ALWAYS returns 0, Even the value is a string "xyle"
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buff));//Always empty, tryed most of Encoding types to check still a blank result.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
            IntPtr hProcess,
            IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
            [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
            int dwSize,
            out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the buffer you give it to fill has a length of `0` since you initialized it completely empty (`new byte[] {}`). Try giving it some room:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
```

Change the number based on how much memory you want to read, and then use the length as your `dwSize` parameter:

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (IntPtr)0x5EFF75B8, buff, (UInt32)buff.Length, out bread);
```

Also, make sure you've got the correct permissions via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6935858/74757). You'll likely need to run the app with elevated permissions.

Comment: And make sure to pass the size of your buffer for dwSize (1024 in this case), not the 10 you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the size of the `buff` array while creating.

```
byte[] buff = new byte[some_size];
```

And also. I believe that the last argument of the `ReadProcessMemory` method declaration should be replaced with

```
out int lpNumberOfBytesRead
```

because of `out` and `ref` arguments are passed by reference. Then you should be able to use `int bread` to cut off excessive bytes from the data in the buffer.

Comment: I just copied pasted that import. I never really understood how i could use the last param. thanks for a use!!.